# Nuxt.js SSR and Static 301 Redirects One Specific Generated Route

Tags: express, vue.js, redirect, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have a nuxt.js app using express that 301 redirects adding a slash. All of the other routes (generated or not) do not do this. I need to make it so no routes redirect. The router does not do this once the SPA takes over.

If it matters, the route `/units/` (when navigating to `/units`). This only happens on initial page load.

Note there are no trailingSlash options or anything like that, so the default (undefined) is used. I have tried that configuration, but I don't want routes without a slash to 404.

Another thing to note, hosting statically on netlify removes the redirect. I realize that this is because of the server configuration. However, my goal is to remove the redirect from development environments, too (e.g. running `nuxt`).

At this point even a clue where to look would be extremely helpful!

Here is the abbreviated nuxt config:

```js
  {
    dir: {
      pages: "pages"
    },
    generate: {
      routes: async () => {
        // logic to create routes
      },
      exclude: []
    },
    ignore: [
      // ignored pages
    ],
    server: {
      port: process.env.NUXT_PORT || 4000,
      host: process.env.NUXT_HOST || "localhost"
    },
    env: {
      // env vars
    },
    ssr: true,
    head: {
      // ...
      script: [
        {
          src: `https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?unknown=polyfill&features=${ features }`,
          async: true,
          crossorigin: "anonymous",
          body: true
        }
      ]
    },
    css: [
      // ...
    ],
    plugins: [
      // ...
    ],
    buildModules: [
      "@nuxtjs/dotenv"
    ],
    modules: [
      "@nuxtjs/axios",
      ["vue-wait/nuxt", { useVuex: true }],
      "@nuxtjs/sitemap"
    ],
    axios: {},
    serverMiddleware: [],
    build: {
      babel: {
        babelrc: false
      },
      corejs: 3,
      shouldPreload: (file, type) => {
        return ["script", "style", "font"].includes(type)
      },
      extend(config, ctx) {
        // ...
        config.node = {
          fs: "empty",
          tls: "empty"
        }
        // ...
      },
      transpile: [
        // ...
      ]
    },
    hooks: {
      nuxt: {
        ready(nuxt) {
          logger.debug(`nuxt:ready`)
        }
      },
      generate: {
        before(generator, generateOptions) {
          logger.debug(`generate:before`)
        }
      },
      render: {
        resourcesLoaded(resources) {
          logger.debug(`render:resourcesLoaded`)
        },
        route(url, result, { params }) {
          logger.debug(`render:route ${ url }`)
          // actual promise returned not relevant
          return Promise.resolve()
        }
      },
      build: {
        before(nuxt, buildOptions) {
          logger.debug(`build:before`)
          // actual promise returned not relevant
          return Promise.resolve()
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

edit:

If I try using `@nuxt/redirect-module` with the following rules, I get infinite redirects.

```js
  redirect: [
    { from: "^/units/$", to: "/units" }
  ],
```

Comment: I still haven't figured this out. R.I.P.

Comment: I never figured this out, but in case someone happens across this, it stopped happening when we started hosting on Netlify  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: That's because, Netlify has option to beautify url.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding the following in the nuxt config along with your redirect rules:

```
router: {
    trailingSlash: true
  }
```

Comment: I purposely left the rule out, however it didn't seem to make a difference when it was there regardless of the value